# Logging out of my windows live account is it possible?

Tags: email, accounts

I added windows live as an account on my phone and it is now using a 3g network and costing me money. Is there any way for me to delete this account?

I have an LG Optimus Quantum. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete the account if it is your primary account, but you can change the account synchronisation to be manual:

1. Settings
2. email+accounts
3. Tap on your account
4. Change download new content to *manually*

You will now need to manually synchronise your email, contacts and calendar.

Alternatively you can turn off your data connection:

1. Settings
2. mobile network
3. Set *Data connection* to *Off*.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are happy with this solution please don't forget to accept it as the answer.